# Add image or video tags to WP Sitemap

Tags: core, sitemap, google-xml-sitemaps

Is there a way to add tags to the default WP core generated sitemaps other than four default ones ('loc', 'lastmod', 'changefreq', 'priority') WP allows using the wp_sitemaps_posts_entry filter?

For instance Google supports multiple meta tags for video or imagery, i.e.: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/video-sitemaps

WP Core seems very inflexible in preventing you from adding additional tags:
[image: class-wp-sitemaps-renderer.php]

Comment: can you remove the screenshot of code, and replace it with a code block containing text? Code in images can't be searched for, it can't be copied or debugged, and it can't be read by users who use assistive technologies. It also can't be indexed in search engines

Comment: I think it's better to switch to another SEO plugin that provides the sitemap functionality with hooks to extend. Slim SEO, Yoast, Rank Math are good choices.